# how to simplify the following geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

so I have the following series:
$$\sum_{i=3}^n 2^{i-1} $$
since it's $2^{i-1}$, I brought down the $2$ and move $1/2$ in front of series. Then
I assumed that I solved the problem with a formula for finite geometric series
so I had it set up as follows: $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=3}^n 2^i = \frac{8(1-2^n)}{1-2} = \frac{1}{2}(2^{n+3} - 8) = 2^{n+2} - 4$$

When I checked the answer it says $2^n - 4$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Look very closely at the number of terms that you're summing over when you use the geometric series formula.

Comment: Your formula only holds if you start at $i=0$.  To fix, subtract out a few terms.

Comment: $i$ starts with $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two equalities in your displayed expression are incorrect.  That is,

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=3}^n 2^i \not= \frac{8(1-2^n)}{1-2} \not= \frac{1}{2}(2^{n+3} - 8) = 2^{n+2} - 4$$

The second mistake is a little easier to see because it should have been

$${8(1-2^n)\over1-2}={8(2^n-1)\over2-1}=2^{n+3}-8$$

(which of course is still the wrong answer because of the first mistake).  A better way to proceed would be

$$\begin{align}
{1\over2}\sum_{i=3}^n2^i&={1\over2}(2^3+2^4+\cdots+2^n)\\
&={2^3\over2}(1+2+\cdots+2^{n-3})\\
&=2^2\left({1-2^{n-2}\over1-2}\right)\\
&=2^2(2^{n-2}-1)\\
&=2^n-4
\end{align}$$